# curl in windows - how do i put a space in the json?

Tags: json, windows, curl

so i have this curl request (running on a windows cmd prompt):

```
curl --insecure -g -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {\"from\":\"someName\",\"message\":\"this is a message\"} https://some/website/here
```

When i run this, i get an error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: is; Host not found
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: a; Host not found
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: message; Host not found
```

Which seems to be because the json is munged up - the spaces are not working!

How would i send this message, if  i wanted spaces to be in the, uh, message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use double quotes **"** and use %20 in url

Just tried on my windows command prompt now. You were missing escape on the DATA part

Your code

```
curl --insecure -g -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {\"from\":\"someName\",\"message\":\"this is a message\"} https://some/website/here
```

should be escaped like this

```
curl --insecure -g -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"from\":\"someName\",\"message\":\"this is a message\"}" https://some/website/here
```

Comment: I cannot accept your answer just yet... but you're right! curl --insecure -g -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {\"from\":\"someName\",\"message\":\""this is a message"\"} https://some/website/here

Comment: When working with command prompts, save it in .BAT batch file so its easier to edit and re-run

Answer (score 4):

You just need to quote your JSON as a string literal:

```
curl --insecure -g -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"from\":\"someName\",\"message\":\"this is a message\"}" https://some/website/here
```

also, use the -V for more info on what is happening (it threw this error "parse error near `}'").

Comment: nice one about the -V, i did not know about that flag

Answer (score 0):

try this (instead of -d ), e.g.:

--data-raw "{"blah":"a string with spaces"}"