# cURL error on whitespace within data field

Tags: bash, shell, curl, whitespace

I'm writing a bash script using cURL to call an API. I'm generating some part of the contents transforming strings coming out from other sources.
From the db the spaces are replaced with "_SPACE_" string for application reasons.
I'm replacing it using

```
ITEM=${M//_SPACE_/ }
```

and then I call cURL as follow:

```
curl ... --data '{"field": "'$ITEM'"}' ...
```

Running the script it returns an exception on curl execution

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 21
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@185ff06c; line: 4, column: 139]
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING ...
```

says that your lib from codehouse is not able to parse the data object which is send via curl. i could imagin that your --data '{"field": "'$ITEM'"}' object fails because of the single quotes '$ITEM'. could u send the complete data object or script ?

Comment: The single quote are not a problem, if I replace the space placeholder with another character (for example ITEM=${M//_SPACE_/_}) the cURL call works fine

Comment: did you echo the replacement and see if its replacing the righ way ? i could recommend to test sed. 
`sed 's/_SPACE_/ /g'`

Comment: if found an issue which is described in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/23914127/5779103. your JSON has to be quoted in a different way. literal string. `curl ... --data "{\"field\" : \"$ITEM\"}" ... `

Comment: copying and pasting the result of the echo in POSTMAN it works, that means the problem is somewhere in the "encoding" of the whitespace